# Adobe Dynamic Tag Manager: Event-Based Rule Upon Unordered List

Tags: web-analytics, adobe-analytics, web-analytics-tools

If there are no Class or DIV designations for the items within this unordered list, how would you go about using the %this.innerHTML% notation to pull which link was clicked in an Event-Based rule?

```
< div class="relatedCategories rowBottomSpace" >

    < strong class="header black short">Related Categories</strong>

    <ul>
      <li>
    <a href="/link1" rel="link 1">LINK 1</a>
        <span>|</span>
    </li>

      <li>
    <a href="/link2" rel="link 2">LINK 2</a>
        <span>|</span>
    </li>

      <li><a href="/link3" rel="link 3">LINK 3</a>
    </li>

  </div>
```

Comment: I assume your Condition's **Element Tag or Selector** is something like `div.relatedCategories`.  If you change it to `div.relatedCategories a` then `this` will reference the link that was clicked

Comment: For those that follow, there is indeed a space between the `div.relatedCategories` and the anchor `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution #1:** Update your selector to be more specific

This is the solution I mentioned in my comment above. Assumption is that your Condition's **Element Tag or Selector** is something like `div.relatedCategories`. If you change it to specifically target links within it: `div.relatedCategories a` then this will reference the link that was clicked.

**Solution #2:** Use a custom condition and data element

Let's say for whatever reason(s) you want to keep the original higher level selector: 
`div.relatedCategories`.

Leave it as such, and then under 
**Rule Conditions > Criteria**
choose **Data > Custom** and then click "Add Criteria".

In the Custom code box, add the following:

```
var target = (event.target) ? event.target : event.srcElement;
_satellite.setVar('linkTarget',target);
return true;
```

This will create a data element called `linkTarget` which will hold an html element object reference to the clicked link. So then you can use `%linkTarget.innerHTML%` or alternatively, back up in the Custom code box you can set  `linkTarget` to be `target.innerHTML` and then reference with `%linkTarget%`.